# Derivative of ellipse

Tags: derivatives

Find $y'=\frac{dy}{dx}$
when: $$2x^2-xy+y^2=1$$

How do I solve this?
Do I start with this?:

$$y=\frac{2x^2+y^2-1}{x}$$

$$y'=\left(\frac{2x^2+y^2-1}{x}\right)'$$

Comment: You want [implicit differentiation](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kouba/CalcOneDIRECTORY/implicitdiffdirectory/ImplicitDiff.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow in this trace:

$$(2x^2-xy+y^2)'=1' \implies 4x-(y+xy')+2yy'=0 \implies y'=\frac{y-4x}{2y-x}.$$

Comment: Why is: $$(xy)'=y+xy'$$

Comment: You should view $y$ as a function on $x$.  @Peppa, Could you upvote me so that I will get 10k reputation:)

Comment: @peppa First, remember that $(fg)'=f'g+fg'$ (the product rule). Also remember that $x'=\frac{\operatorname d\!x}{\operatorname d\!x}=1$. Now, use the product rule, where $f=x$ and $g=y$.